# opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ]--Angular and Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am running my angular application with `Node.js 18`, but it is giving me an error,

```
error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error
```

I have checked others answers on forum but not working, I do not want to downgrade I want to fix the error so app can work on `Node.js 18`, can anyone help?

I tried answers on forum with `json.package` but it is not working, lot of them is on `react`, but I am using `angular`. Anyone have idea?